# Can't see Spring Boot Actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'd like to exposure all actuator endpoints to check the metrics,so I added this to my application.properties file:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

The application has a token-based authentication set up. When I try to open `http://localhost:8080/actuator` on my browser, I have the following error:

```
{
"error": "Missing auth token header for call:/actuator"
}
```

In the Postman, when I try it with a valid token, the actuator endpoints are shown.
Is there any way to show the actuator endpoint without getting any token?

Comment: How are you handling the auth token security?

Comment: You have to give more information about your authentication.